# Java map sequence

Tags: java, hashmap

```
    private java.util.HashMap<Character, Boolean> letters = new java.util.HashMap<Character, Boolean>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        letters.put(letter, false);
        System.out.println(letter);
        letter++;
    }
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Boolean> v : letters.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(v.getKey());
    }
```

When print the letter I can get a b c d e f g .....but after store in the hashmap it return me f g d e b c..... not in sequence why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HashMap` is not ordered. If you want to retrieve the entries in the insertion order, use `LinkedHashMap` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.HashMap` is not ordered collection.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap is not neither sorted nor order, you can use [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). It is sorted by natural order or custom comparison rules.

An example :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String,Double> map = new HashMap<String,Double>();
        ValueComparator bvc =  new ValueComparator(map);
        TreeMap<String,Double> sorted_map = new TreeMap(bvc);

        map.put("A",99.5);
        map.put("B",67.4);
        map.put("C",67.5);
        map.put("D",67.3);

        System.out.println("unsorted map");
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("key/value: " + key + "/"+map.get(key));
        }

        sorted_map.putAll(map);

        System.out.println("results");
        for (String key : sorted_map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("key/value: " + key + "/"+sorted_map.get(key));
        }
    }

}

class ValueComparator implements Comparator {

  Map base;
  public ValueComparator(Map base) {
      this.base = base;
  }

  public int compare(Object a, Object b) {

    if((Double)base.get(a) < (Double)base.get(b)) {
      return 1;
    } else if((Double)base.get(a) == (Double)base.get(b)) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hashmap is not ordered..I only knew this after using TreeMap..but that works well for me when dealing with dates